# sql get a unique combination of two columns without duplications (unique values in each column)

Tags: sql, ms-access

Sample data:

```
a            b
-------      ---------
1       /     2     
1       /     3
2       /     1
3       /     1
3       /     2
2       /     1
3       /     2
```

I have the above sample data. What i want is to select the unique (and distinct) rows of the combination A and B. In the above example the only matching results are

```
A            B
-------      ---------
1      /      2
2      /      1
```

db used: access
Tanks

Comment: and why not a 3?

Comment: Do you want to count unique B items for each A value? If not, clarify rules for "unique (and distinct) rows of the combination A and B".